# How do you find the $x$ coordinate of an equation, when the gradient is $0$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Given that

$$f(x) = 3x^3 - 3x^2 + x - 7$$
Find the $x$-coordinate of the point on the curve where the gradient is $0$.

How do I figure this out?

Comment: gradient means derivative here, just in case you're struggling with notations

Answer (score 2):

**Hints.** Let $f(x) = 3x^3 -3x^2 + x - 7$. First find $f'(x)$ which will be a second degree polynomial. Next solve the equation $f'(x) = 0$ which you should be able to solve with the quadratic equation.

Answer (score 1):

Find the derivative of $f(x)$ $$f'(x) = 9x^2 -6x + 1$$
Now we know the slope/gradient is zero when $f'(x)=0$.

So we can solve $$9x^2 -6x + 1 = 0 \\ (3x-1)^2 = 0$$ Yields one solution (repeated root) $$x=\frac{1}{3}$$